# update to boostrap 4 implicit call of function undefined asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am recently working on a task of an existing website, updating Bootstrap from version 3.3.4 to 4.4.1  . The problem that I encountered is when you implicitly call a js function in the cshtml, function is undefined even though it's in the Bundle.config file and I think that it's correctly arranged. But when you call a function inside of ex. a button on a onclick attribute the function works fine, also the called functions works when you explicitly add the script reference ( ex. ) inside the cshtml file. I'm still new at web development and in mvc, have anyone encountered this? can someone help me, I would really appreaciate a helping hand..

**Bundle.config**

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/js").Include(    
        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
         "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
          "~/Scripts/login.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js",
             "~/Scripts/bootstrap-submenu-min.js",
           "~/Scripts/loyalty-members.js",
        "~/Scripts/prepaid-card.js",
        "~/Scripts/contactus.js",
        "~/Scripts/loading.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js",
        "~/Scripts/home.js",
        "~/Scripts/myprofile.js",
        "~/Scripts/alertmsg.js",
        "~/Scripts/merchants.js",
        "~/Scripts/flipclock/flipclock.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
         "~/scripts/adjustmentbs4/navbar-customize.js" --> this is a test js file with function with alert
         ));
```

**This is just a test function to call inside the cshtml**

`function ShowDropdownMenu() {
    alert("Test");

}`

**This is the script inside the cshmtl, as you can see the test function ShowDropdownMenu is called, but originally below that is the alertMessagePrompt function that is also when called is undefined or not defined. but I tested other functions as well like that ShowDropdownMenu and it has the same error the alertMessagePrompt function**

```
<script>
   ShowDropdownMenu();
    if ('@TempData["Message"]' != null && '@TempData["Message"]' != "") {
        if ('@TempData["pc_result"]' == '0') {

        } else {
            alertMessagePrompt("Registration Error", "@TempData["Message"]", 1, [["Ok", "btnOkCloseId", 2, "closeMsgPrompt()"]]);
        }
        changeValue("pc_firstname");
        changeValue("pc_middlename");
        changeValue("pc_lastname");
        validateMobile("pc_mobile");
        changeValue("pc_bdate");
        validateEmail('pc_youremail');
        changeValue("pc_cardName");
        changeValue("pc_cityResidence");
        changeValue("pc_cityWork");
    }
</script>
```

**I've also tested from the original version of this project, I first updated the jquery and functions implicitly called inside cshtml are still working fine, but after updating bootstrap 4 that is when the error begins.**

Comment: it's helpful to provide some piece of code to make things more clear

Comment: Check if you have provided the relevant scripts and if they are present then check if they are in proper order. Order matters for JS scripts.

Comment: @ysfaran i've updated my post

Comment: @noobprogrammer ive updated my post hope it gives more detail

Comment: @noobprogrammer from the original version of this project where I haven't done any changes at all, I've tried updating the jQuery using nuget package, and the functions called works the same, after updating to bootstrap 4 that is when the functions became undefined the you need to add the script reference for it to work at the cshtml file, but when u use the functions in an html element attribute ex. onclick the functions works just fine.